# Delete record with ajax via id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Having trouble deleting a record from mysql databse using ajax/jquery. Issue I am having is that it does not delete from the database but does delete from the list. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".deleteitem").click(function(){

    var parent = $(this).closest('li');
    var id = parent.attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" +id,
      URL: "delete.php",
      success: function(msg){
        $('#'+id).remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My php file delete.php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

$id = $_POST['id'];

if (isset($id)) {
  $query = "DELETE FROM img_slider WHERE id = '$id'";
  mysqli_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
}
```

The HTML markup:

```
<li id='".$row['id']."'>
<a href='#' class='deleteitem'><img src='../img/delete.png'></a>
</li>
```

Comment: The data format is `data: {"id": id}`

Comment: Is that _all_ your PHP code? Where do you connect to the database?

Comment: you should see what delete.php does. you can use $_REQUEST instead $_POST and call delete.php?id=... and see what will happen. If it works return $_POST and debug your params in ajax

Comment: @karthikr no luck there.

Comment: It might be failing to connect and since you have ot echoing "failed to connect". The ajax will see that as a succesful response regardless of deletion or not.....perhaps you should only echo something if the deletion was succesful.....to further debug the problem

Answer (score 2):

Firstly test to make sure calling the delete file with a valid id works.  The javascript below should work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {
  $('.deleteitem').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
    $.get('delete.php',{ id: id}).done(function(data) {
      if(data=='Error, insert query failed') {
          // dont delete from list
          alert('Failed to delete '+id);
      } else {
          //delete from list
          $('#'+id).remove();
          alert('Deleted '+id);
      }
    });
  });
});
//-->
</script>
```

EDIT: updated the script to assist parent-id handling.

Are you able to say where the error is coming from?  Most modern browsers should offer you some insight into what line, or what section the error is occurring on.

The script above should replace all your javascript.

Comment: I get an error with the above javascript. Delete.php is in working order.

Comment: edited to assist in basix syntax errors and to help give you some alerts as to whats happening

Comment: The error seems to be at: `alert ('deleted +' id);` - Much appreciative of your time here.

Comment: Fixed the issue, concatonater ('+' character) inside instead of outside the quotations